# Angular generate environment

Tags: angular

I am using Angular cli 16. I run following command to generate `ENVIRONMENTS` folder in the project:

```
ng generate enviroments
```

I get following error message:

> Error: A collection and schematic is required during execution.

I could generate folder and files of `ENVIRONMENTS` manually, but I worry to miss some additional configurations.

Comment: Seems like a typo. It should be `ng generate environments` not `enviroments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did spelling mistake.

Right command is

`ng generate environments`

you can also check Angular documentations
https://angular.io/cli/generate#environments-command